# How do i flip the value of AudioListener.pause like a bool

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

I am working on a menu script but I have a little bit of a problem. Whenever I pause my game, I want the music to stop. So I do this:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
{
    isPaused = !isPaused;
    AudioListener.pause =! AudioListener.pause;
}
```

What this does is it makes the audio works the first time I play the game and stops it forever after that. **How Do I Fix This Problem?**

Feedback is always appreciated **;)**

Answer (score 0):

Since your assigning a "isPaused" variable, have you tried just setting it to equal that?

```
isPaused = !isPaused;
AudioListener.pause = isPaused;
```

Im really not sure why your code wouldnt work though. AudioListener.pause is a bool and you should be able to use the "!" function on it.

Comment: Maybe also add a `Debug.Log( " ... ");` and make sure the function is running for the second time you click.

Comment: I know it works when I press escape again because I have a visual for  isPaused